# Read text from tag <font color="red"> and Print over console

Tags: java, webdriver

I have a HTML code where a text present under a tag
                font color="red" Text Message /font
  Please suggest a code to read/get text and print it over output console

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ : Yes i am using driver.findElement(by.tagName(font color="red")).getText();

Comment: Try `driver.getElementsByTagName("font").getText();`

Comment: Got it 
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("h4")).getText());

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this : 
http://xahlee.info/js/js_get_elements.html 
and for the output just use console.log()

Comment: I am using driver.findElement(by.tagName(font color="red")).getText(); but its not working

Comment: Got it 
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.tagName("h4")).getText());

Answer (score 0):

I would try to use `getAttribute` instead of `getText`, smth. like  `System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("write_here_your_locator")).getAttribute("color"));`